# iOS Change the color in the UIButton which was created in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift

This is my working code for buttons in a scrollview that are generated from  a for loop.How can i access each of them to change they properties or colors.

```
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var namesOfMuscless = ["ALL","|","CHEST","|","BACK","|","BICEPS","|","TRICEPS","|","DELTOIDS","|","TRAPS","|","ABS","|","OBLIQUES","|","QUADS","|","CALVES","|","INNER THIGHS","|","HAMSTRING","|","GLUTES"]
var nameOfMusclesSizes = [Int]()
var nameOfMusclesSizesFinal = [Int]()
var addFinalSize = 0
var scrollerSize = 0
var pixelAdjustment = 9

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //One letter 20px




    for sizeAdd in 0..<self.namesOfMuscless.count {
       nameOfMusclesSizes.append(namesOfMuscless[sizeAdd].characters.count)

    }

    for sizeAddFinal in 0..<self.namesOfMuscless.count {
        if(sizeAddFinal<1){
            nameOfMusclesSizesFinal.append(0)
        }else{

            for counter in 0..<self.nameOfMusclesSizesFinal.count {
            addFinalSize=nameOfMusclesSizesFinal[counter]
            scrollerSize=nameOfMusclesSizesFinal[counter]+13
            }

            nameOfMusclesSizesFinal.append(nameOfMusclesSizes[sizeAddFinal-1]+addFinalSize)
        }
        print(nameOfMusclesSizesFinal[sizeAddFinal])

    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(scrollerSize*pixelAdjustment-50),200)
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default



    for index in 0..<self.namesOfMuscless.count {
        let frame1 = CGRect(x:(nameOfMusclesSizesFinal[index]*pixelAdjustment),y: 20, width:namesOfMuscless[index].characters.count*pixelAdjustment, height: 30 )
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
        button.setTitle(namesOfMuscless[index], forState: .Normal)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        button.addTarget(namesOfMuscless[index], action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)
    }
}

func buttonClick(sender:UIButton){
    if(sender.currentTitle=="|"){

    }else{
      print(sender.currentTitle)
    }
}
```

How can i change the color of the selected button if it is in a for loop.
I have tried it for a couple of hours but nothing worked out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give each button a tag, and set it to the index of the for loop:

```
button.tag = index
```

and then put the button in a Dictionary `[Int : UIButton]` for use later

```
myButtons[index] = button
```

So, you could create the global variable `var myButtons: [Int : UIButton] = [:]`, and then add the following lines in your for loop

```
button.tag = index
myButtons[index] = button
```

Then, you can access each button by using its tag, `var buttonToEdit: UIButton = myButtons[tagToUse]`.

So, for example, you could store each muscle in a list with its index

```
var indexes: [String : Int] = [
    "ALL" : 0, "CHEST" : 1,
    "BACK" : 2, "BICEPS" : 3,
    "TRICEPS" : 4,"DELTOIDS" : 5,
    "TRAPS" : 6, "ABS" : 7,
    "OBLIQUES" : 8, "QUADS" : 9,
    "CALVES" : 10, "INNER THIGHS" : 11,
    "HAMSTRING" : 12, "GLUTES" : 13
]
```

And then get a button from the list `myButtons` list based on the index stored in `indexes`. For example, if you wanted to get the button for *ABS*, you could use

```
var absIndex: Int = indexes["ABS"] ?? 0
var absButton: UIButton? = myButtons[absIndex]
```

Comment: @Arslan No problem! If you want to [accept this as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), you can click the check mark on the left of the answer